# Mongoose query reference current object keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to compare the object keys in order to make decision, something like below.

Schema:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  price:      {type: Number},
  msrp:       {type: Number},
});
```

Query:

Note: This is just prototype of my intention and not a legal code.

```
Item.find({'(100 - ((price * 100)/msrp))' : {$gt: 60 }})
```

Where msrp and price inside $gt should be the values of the current element of find processing.

Comment: What is your mongo version ?

Comment: Client is "mongoose": "^4.13.9" and the server is sitting on mlab.com

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `$where` operator. Just be aware that it will be fairly slow as it has to execute Javascript code for every record, so combine with indexed queries if you can. You can read more about the `$where` operator [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where)

```
Item.find( { $where: function() { return this.price > 100-((this.price*100)/this.msrp) } } );
```